# Load CKAsset into UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift3, uiwebview, xcode8, cloudkit

I am trying to load a PDF File stored in a publicDatabase as a CKAsset, the code worked well on an existing application, published last year. However I now get the following error

Cannot convert value of type 'NSData' to type 'Data' in coercion

here is the code -

```
if  docType == "PDF" || docType == "pdf" {
   if let asset1 = record.object(forKey: "documentFile") as? CKAsset {
      let doc1Data : NSData? = NSData(contentsOf:asset1.fileURL)
      let path = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).appendingPathComponent(filename)
      let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(filename)
       do {
       try doc1Data!.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .atomic)
       } catch {
       print(error)
       }
       self.docWebView.load(doc1Data! as Data, mimeType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL() as URL)
       self.filenameURL = [(fileURL)]
}
```

I'm sure there must be a simple explanation, but I cannot see the problem

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Alas I still get the error - Cannot convert value of type 'NSData' to type 'Data' in coercion relating to the `self.docWebView.loadData(doc1Data as Data?, MIMEType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL() as URL)` line of code

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the below line :

```
let doc1Data : NSData? = NSData(contentsOf:asset1.fileURL)
```

to

```
let doc1Data = NSData(contentsOf:asset1.fileURL)
```

Comment: Alas I still get the error - Cannot convert value of type 'NSData' to type 'Data' in coercion relating to the `self.docWebView.loadData(doc1Data as Data?, MIMEType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL() as URL)` line of code

Answer (score 0):

It would appear the answer is simple, change the load Data to loadRequest and reference the URL of the document having obtained it from the CKAsset

```
if  docType == "PDF" || docType == "pdf" {
if let asset1 = record.object(forKey: "documentFile") as? CKAsset {
let doc1Data : NSData! = NSData(contentsOf:asset1.fileURL)
let path = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).appendingPathComponent(filename)
do {
   try doc1Data!.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .atomic)
   let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
   let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
   self.docWebView?.loadRequest(urlRequest)
  } catch {
   print(error)
   }
}
```